# ROOT(CERN): Plot an figure with error bars using data from an csv file

Tags: c++, csv, root-framework

I'm trying to read data from a .csv file, which contains 4 columns: "x","y","Standard Deviation" and "Uncertainty". I want to plot a scatter diagram with error bars, which represent the uncertainty red from the .csv file. I run the following codes in root's REPL:

```
auto rdf = ROOT::RDF::MakeCsvDataFrame("./file.csv")
auto g1 = rdf.GraphAsymmErrors("x","y","","","Uncertainty","Uncertainty");
```

but I get an error:

```
ROOT_prompt_1:1:15: error: no member named 'GraphAsymmErrors' in 'ROOT::RDataFrame'
```

Meanwhile I can run the code below correctly:

```
auto g2=rdf.Graph("x","y");
g2->SetMarkerStyle(6);
g2->Draw();
```

, which confuses me because in [the document of ROOT](https://root.cern/doc/master/classROOT_1_1RDataFrame.html), the Graph() method and GraphAsymmErrors() method both seem to be the method of RDataFrame, so I think it should not show the error above.

Also, my root's version is 6.26, installed on Ubuntu 22.04 via snap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GraphAsymmErrors` doesn't seem to exist in the [v6.26 documentation](https://root.cern/doc/v626/classROOT_1_1RDataFrame.html). The documentation you linked was for the master branch. You'll probably have to update to a nightly-build or wait for the next release in order to use that function.

In the meantime I would recommend you use `RDataFrame::Take()` on the respective branches to get them as `std::vector`s, and use the `TGraphAsymmErrors` constructor directly.